# How to draw line by scratching on map using OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, openlayers

Is it possible to draw line by scratching on the map using OpenLayers? I tried some examples, all the examples are drawing by clicking. I want to draw by scratching, just like drawing in normal life on the paper. Is it possible to implement by OpenLayers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hold down the shift key while drawing to activate freehand mode.